# d3 dynamic curved line in force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, bezier

I'd like to have a dynamic bezier curve for the line in a force layout like this [cytoscape example](http://jsbin.com/urabis/8/edit), is possible in d3? see this [d3 example](http://jsbin.com/otibev/5/edit) but use arc.
I have no idea of the algorithm, someone has an idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic behaviour"?

Comment: Well yes, but I'm not sure what's dynamic about it. Is all you want a curved line?

Comment: How does the example you've linked to not fulfill your requirements?

Comment: no, because arc behaviour is different from bezier curves behaviour,

Comment: and the central control point? "Easy" is not a solution, how can I calculate it?

Comment: As a start, you could try the "T" line drawing command, which doesn't require you to specify a control point. The position of the control point really depends on what you want it to look like and you can use the same functionality that you use to compute the line points to calculate it.

Comment: Can you post a code example?

Comment: That would be the example you've linked to with A "T" in the path definition followed by the points.

Comment: i've read this http://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js and make this  

path.attr("d", function (d) {
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "T" + d.target.x 
            + "," + d.target.y;
});
but only creates straight lines

Comment: This excellent D3 question is closed for no reason, by people who obviously do not have a clue about this library. :(

Comment: I think the moderator misunderstood the question.  The question shows an example of using d3 to draw *arc* lines, and the follow-up post shows how to draw *bezier* curves using cytoscape.  The question is how to use d3 to draw bezier curves.  I don't know how to re-open a question, so here's the answer:  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4600693

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've see the [cytoscape](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/) library and with this algorytm works

```
function tick() {
     path.attr("d", function (d) {
          var coordinatesP = findEdgeControlPoints(d);
          return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "S" + coordinatesP.xp + "," + coordinatesP.yp + " " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
     });
     hashTable = {};
          nodes.attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
               .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; });
}

var findEdgeControlPoints = function (d) {
        var midPointX = (d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2;
        var midPointY = (d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2;

        var displacementX, displacementY;

        displacementX = d.target.y - d.source.y;
        displacementY = d.source.x - d.target.x;

        var displacementLength = Math.sqrt(displacementX * displacementX + displacementY * displacementY);

        displacementX /= displacementLength;
        displacementY /= displacementLength;

        var distanceFromMidpoint = findPathDeltaControlPoint(d);


        var xp = midPointX + displacementX * distanceFromMidpoint;
        var yp = midPointY + displacementY * distanceFromMidpoint;

        return {xp : xp, yp : yp};

    };
    var findPathDeltaControlPoint = function (edge) {
        /*caso statico il primo al centro e tutti gli altri ai lati*/
        /*conto le occorrenze */
        var pairId,
            delta,
            TICK = 20;
        pairId = edge.source.id > edge.target.id ?
                edge.target.id + '-' + edge.source.id :
                edge.source.id + '-' + edge.target.id;

        if (hashTable[pairId] == undefined) {
            hashTable[pairId] = [];
        }
        if (edge[pairId] == undefined) {
            edge[pairId] = [];
        }
        if (edge[pairId].length == 0) {
            edge[pairId].push(pairId);
        }
        hashTable[pairId].push(edge);
        // Ceck if is the first occurence
        var pairIdOccurence = hashTable[pairId].length;
        if (pairIdOccurence == 1) {
            delta = 0;
        } else if (pairIdOccurence > 1) {
            // Check if is equal
            if (pairIdOccurence % 2 == 0) {
                delta = (TICK * pairIdOccurence) / 2;
            } else {
                delta = -((TICK * (pairIdOccurence - 1)) / 2);
            }
        }
        return delta;
    };
```