# How can I make straight line instead of curve line in d3 force layout?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I need to render an arrow marker in the middle of the edge.
My code (JSFiddle) can be found at `[link][1]`.

But how can I make straight line instead of curve line?

`[1]:` http://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/1hxcqL1c/

Comment: Change your tick function so instead of returning a curve it returns a line : https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098879/d3-force-layout-straight-line-instead-of-curve-for-links-but-only-for-some-lin) might help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550195/d3-dynamic-curved-line-in-force-layout

Comment: How can i add the  arrow in the middle of the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your tick function you have this :

```
path.attr("d", function (d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    });
```

The easiest way is just to straighten out the SVG:Curve you made so make dr=0:

```
path.attr("d", function (d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
            //dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        dr = 0;
        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    });
```

this :

```
return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + endX + "," + endY;
```

this returns a bezier curve, so 'dr' is how much curve basically, see this for more info : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/path-element.html

Read as much as you can and try understand your code !

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/1hxcqL1c/1/

Comment: HI AJ_91 but my problem is to render the arrow in the middle of the link.

Comment: I have tried the marker-mid its not working out for me.

Comment: ahh okay give me a sec, only took in the second question about straightening the lines :)

Comment: the arrows are in the middle ? isnt that what you asked for ?

Comment: ya i need it in the middle of each link.:)

Comment: Ya AJ once again you did it :)

Comment: But is that possible to overlap the same line.

Comment: haha confused me then. Try understand the tick function which renders the curve/line. Read up on the link i showed on SVG bezier curves, that describes the positions that its coming back with. You need to read your code and understand whats being made. Yeah you can over lap the same line, but why would you want to do that ? The data you have there is best used with curves as you can see what direction its pointing in

Comment: Im new to D3 :) its very simple AJ i want to  show the arrows in middle of the link . I search many example i didn't got any solution for this. At last i got this link.